# Show that $I$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are contractible.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

**Show that $I$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are contractible.**

A space $X$ is said to be ***contractible*** if the identity map $i_X:X\to X$ is nulhomotopic.

If $i_I$ is the identity function of $I:=[0,1]$ in $I$, could I consider the homotopy $H:I\times I\to I$ such that $H(x,t)=tx$, and so the identity function would be homotopic to the zero constant function and with this would it be ready? Does the same function serve to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible? Thank you very much.

Comment: $H(x,1)$ is a constant map?

Comment: At t = 0. @mucciolo..

Comment: No a differnt function is needed for R.

Comment: @WilliamElliot We could have left him thinking more about it :p

Comment: @WilliamElliot Why doesn't the same function work for $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It would have to be H:R×I -> R